# Why brushes are not exposed directly instead of Color properties for a control?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

In general, the backcolor settings of the Control will be drawn in OnPaint() with brush created with the backcolor of control like below,

```
using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(this.BackColor))
{
   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.ClipRectangle);
}
```

My question is, why the colors are exposed outside and why brushes are created internally.

Instead of exposing colors properties like Color BackColor, Color ForeColor. **Why can't we expose the brushes directly to control like Brush BackgroundBrush, Brush ForegroundBrush?**

Regards,

Comment: (not an expert of GDI here, programmed for some years in C++ for WinAPI, but nothing fancy)... I think that non-solid brushes are one of the least used parts of GDI :-)

Comment: It seems you are coming from wpf world (or similar), as controls there indeed exposing [brushes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.foreground(v=vs.110).aspx). The question though is dull, what problem will it solve? Winforms is old, try to program with pure winapi to understand how much valuable it was at its time, but for current standards its just old. If you implement custom painting then you can as well add properties you mention, again, do you have problem with making e.g. `BackgroundBrush` or what?

Comment: @Sinatr - No problem at all. Just curious to know why Colors are used instead of Brush.

Comment: Back in days brushes were system resources (objects), you had to [dispose them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8253398/1997232). Making property of `Brush` type would allocate it for each control or require some ways to share references, etc. (disregards there are [predefined brushes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/471700/1997232)).Color is easy. Newer frameworks don't have problems with it, e.g. wpf [SolidColorBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have to be disposed (yet it also has predefined brushes, this time for convenience).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a huge distinction between the two types.  System.Drawing.Color is a simple value type, a *struct*.  Doesn't do anything special, it basically just stores the alpha, red, green and blue components of the color.  No muss, no fuss.

SolidBrush has a lot more heft.  It is the kind of class that is very cheap to create (less than a microsecond) but very expensive to store.  It is a *wrapper class* for an operating system object, brushes are stored on the desktop heap.  For appcompat reasons, going all the way back to Win3, all apps that run on the desktop need to share that heap and it cannot store more than 65535 objects. That forced the Microsoft programmer to implement IDisposable to ensure the native object can be destroyed early enough, before the garbage collector gets around to calling the finalizer.  And for this code to use the `using` statement.

Do note the [Brushes class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brushes(v=vs.110).aspx), it has handy-dandy properties that provide a solid brush of a named color.  Pretty similar to how the Color type can provide a named color, like Color.AliceBlue vs Brushes.AliceBlue.  Convenient, but not that pretty under the hood, the brush object lives for the lifetime of the app.  A somewhat acceptable compromise, assumption is that the app uses the brush often and that there are too few named colors to risk exhausting the desktop heap.  Not otherwise usable in this case, `this.BackColor` can be any color.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are rarely used. In many years of programming (first directly for WinAPI, then with ATL/WTL, then in Winforms) I haven't ever used a non-solid brush. Their use is very specific (and for hatchbrushes I can't even imagine what it could be in a colored world :-) )

I'll add that I always hated that I had to create/destroy a brush to paint with a solid color :-) (but I loved the `GetSysColorBrush` that didn't need destroying)

If you really need them, you can easily subclass your favourite control and overload the `OnPaint` message.